# Assign colour by group in coord_polar (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to assign a different color to each group of instances in radian chart (ggplot2, R).

A similar code works well for me in bar charts with ggplot2 but not in the case of the radar chart.

```
colores = c(rgb(79, 129, 189, max=255), rgb(155, 187, 89, max=255), rgb(75, 172, 198, max=255), rgb(44, 77, 117, max=255),rgb(95, 117, 48, max=255))

ggplot(data.m, aes(x = Preguntas, y = Valor, col = Comision, group = Comision), color=Comision) +
  geom_polygon(fill=NA) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme (text = element_text(size=9.5)) +
  theme ( plot.title = element_text(family="Helvetic",
                                    size=rel(2),
                                    vjust=2,
                                    face="plain")) + 
  labs(x = "",y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, hjust=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colores) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.5,1))
```

I need you to assign a different color for each commission, currently it does but without responding to the patterns in the "colores" list.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data.m)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data.m, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

From your script, you  map `color = Comision`. So, you have to use `scale_color_manual`, not `scale_fill_manual`.